# How can I share directions/route from Google Maps App?

Tags: google-maps

In the web based version of Google Maps it is possible to create a link to a set of directions between two places and send it to a friend in an email or instant message. For example I can send someone a link to show them some walking directions.

Is it possible to create a link similar to this in the Google Maps App for Android?

I know how to create the route with the directions in the Maps app. I just don't see any way to share it - for example by E-Mail or SMS. I'd also like that the resulting link will work on a non-Android phone, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not been able to find out how to do that either. However, I have found you can share places by clicking on them and then selecting "Share this place."

Comment: Thanks. Shame it can't be done. Your suggestion of "Share this place" will have to do.

Comment: It is basically all you need. The user that receives the shared place can then compute his own directions (e.g. based on his current location). IMHO adding a feature that shares directions would be feature creep.

Comment: Google Maps App version 9.4.0 already allows sharing of directions. Select the "..." icon on top right while in directions window, and choose "Share directions". It will share the full directions information to your selected apps (email, hangout, etc). You may have problem doing that with twitter (due to the 140 chars limitation). You might want to add this to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to create these links in the Google Maps app.

Answer (score 2):

As of the date of this posting you can not do this in the android app.  HOWEVER you can access it through Google maps website.  So instead of using your app navigate to Google maps through your browser.  It will take a bit longer to load so only do this if you have to share the map or directions.  Seems like a natural to be able to share this function via sms to non smart phones.  It equals free advertising for Google.  I hope they add this soon to the mobile app!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to do it via a browser either: what is shared is not the chosen route, but just starting and end points of the journey, but the particular chosen route is not, so the recipient then has to choose a route themselves, which totally defeats the point.